# Deixar setInterval ativo causa lentidão no site?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

Por exemplo, tenho um setInterval que ele vai ficar de 1 em 1 segundo verificando se o chat da empresa está com algum atendente online. Se algum atendente ficar online, eu dou um clearInterval e paro a função, mas, se nenhum atendente ficar online, ele continua rodando.

Isso pode, depois de um certo tempo, deixar o site lento?

## EDIT

A resposta do DVD não me está muito claro, só quero exatamente saber, pode ou não ficar lento? La so está dizendo que é recomendado não usar, só que eu preciso usar. Só queria ter certeza mesmo.

Obrigado!

Comment: Deixa sim amigo, com um grande número de requisições em pequenos períodos de tempo o navegador fica sobrecarregado.

Comment: Oi Lucas! Cara, como eu disse na resposta marcada, usar setInterval em requisições ao servidor pode gerar travamentos e gargalos, logo, sim, o site fica lento.

Comment: Vc pode usar setInterval, que é quase a mesma coisa e vai fazer as requisições de forma organizada, mesmo em um intervalo de 1 segundo. Mas o ideal mesmo é aumentar esse tempo para não sobrecarregar o servidor.

Comment: Entendi! Muito obrigado a todos!!!